# Jquery ui sortable issue with css3 transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am facing some position issue when I used jquery ui sortable with css3 transform.

`jsfiddle`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/hzvLfhxd/2/

Here I have used jquery UI sortable, also css3 transform scale and translate.

There is a problem while sorting from top to bottom.

A gap appears between the cursor and the object while sorting to bottom or trying to sort bottom objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Remove `transform:translate(50px)  scale(0.777);` from css(.wrapper) and check

Comment: I needed to use transform.

Comment: than remove only 'scale(0.777)' from transform

Comment: Hi SimarjeetSingh,

I have to use both scale and translate in my application. Is their any solution with exist both.??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove width:500px;height:600px; from .wrapper.

I am assuming you want to remove the gap at the end of sorting div. Correct me if I am wrong in that.

Comment: No Shouvik. I wanted to remove the gap between cursor and sorting element while sorting to bottom.

You can see the issue if you try to sort first element to bottom. While moving to bottom the gap between cursor and element is increasing.

Comment: oh ! my mistake. Then it has to be something related to scaling.